# How would I satisfy contraints of a cloth simulation with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to write a cloth simulation using python + numpy
I have a working cloth simulation using python and loops. However the numpy version doesn't work as expected.
tmp is an array of vertex positions ordered by edge vertices.
| edge1.Point a | edge1.Point b
| edge2.Point a | edge2.Point b

```
    pos1 = tmp[::2]
    pos2 = tmp[1::2]
    
    delta = pos2-pos1
    deltaLen = np.linalg.norm(delta, axis=1)
    f = (delta.T * (deltaLen - 0.2)).T * self.k
    tmp[::2] += f
    tmp[1::2] -= f
```

This is the snippet that looks at the distances between link pairs and then sets the new distances.

I've included an image of a grid running the simulation where the goal is to have all edges 0.2 in length, with a start length of 0.25
The code works with looping through arrays, but not with numpy

[Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH2M5.png)

Comment: *"However the numpy version doesn't work as expected."*  It will be easier for someone to help you if you give more details.  What output did you get?  What did you expect to get?  Also, if you have code that works with loops, you should include that in the question, so readers can clearly see what the expected behavior is.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because your slices are not the same length?

```
import numpy as np

tmp = np.random.rand(7)

pos1 = tmp[::2]
pos2 = tmp[1::2]

print(pos1.shape, pos2.shape)
>>> (4,) (3,)

# make array slice same length
pos1 = tmp[:-1:2]
pos2 = tmp[1::2]

print(pos1.shape, pos2.shape)
>>> (3,) (3,)
```

Comment: it is not , but thanks for the suggestion. I will update the question for specificity. The problem was that the indexes were only visited once with numpy array ops, what I needed was ufunc.at  to visit indexes multiple times.